# Internal compiler error: Specified cast is not valid. in NetNatives.target

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

In a past 2 weeks. I've been seeing this in my error log. And no matter how hard I tried. It persists.

I've been working on my project everything is fine. I can see all error and I fix it. I can still debug in in "Debug" mode and everything is fine. But whenever I tried to build it in "Release" solution configuration. The error showed up. [This](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AsPczr3-hqPBiqM87oxAHaiZJnuyiA) is a full log of it. I wish I could put the log in here. But I'm not sure where is the actual error of it. The full log is about 2 MB

I have absolutely no idea if this is my fault or Visual studio fault. But I'm sure my code is fine since I can still test it in "Debug" solution configuration. It just refuses to build on release.

Here is what I tried so far:

- Delete "obj" and "bin" folder. (not help)
- Build other projects on both "Debug" and "Release" (they work just fine)
- Build on another machine (still, show the same error)
- Update everything to the latest version (not work either)
- Revert back to where it still works last build (not working anymore)

I'm totally giving up. I have absolutely no clue what am I going to do. If anyone knows how to fix it or have some solution please let me know.

Edit: It's appear to be a visual studio issue. And it fixed on latest patch: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/311904/cant-create-app-package-for-windows-store.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue should be caused by the Humanizer Nuget version 2.4.2, see the issue in Github:

https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer/issues/734

The workaround is to downgrade Humanizer Nuget package to v2.3.3.

Note that: please pay attention to your privacy of your project.

Comment: At first when I downgrade Humanizer. I can now debug my project set to "Release". Then a few moment later it came back. I even remove Humanizer altogether. And it still persist again! Oof!

Comment: It is odd, I just download your sample and downgrade the Humanizer to v2.3.3, then I can build the project and deploy the project in release mode on my device. Could you try to clearn and rebuild, even delete the obj and bin folder to try it again?

Comment: It work just fine when it build for sideload. But it not build when I build for windows store :( Here is what it said: https://1drv.ms/t/s!AsPczr3-hqPBiqdZHkKMnFOD2PS-3g

Comment: nvm. It appear to be visual studio issue and it fix in a latest patch. -_-' https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/311904/cant-create-app-package-for-windows-store.html